# how to sync GameObject variable in photon network?

Tags: unity-game-engine, networking, photon

[image]

I am making Network game using Unity. I want to configure my network using PUN2. In particular, I notice that I can synchronize several basic variables through the OnPhotonSerializeView () method. However, this does not include custom classes such as GameObject and Transform. So what should I do to synchronize the Target Transform in that inspector view?

Answer (score 0):

There are a few ways to tackle this. It depends on what you need this target for, and if it makes since for the object to exist on the other clients if it's not being targeted by any object.

Suppose you have Player that is synced, and a blue ball and a red ball in the scene.
The player has a ball that they are "holding". You want to trigger a synchronization so on all clients, if the player is holding a red ball it will hold it for all clients, and if they hold the blue ball it will do so for all clients.

The problem linking the blue ball in one client to all the blue balls in everyone else's client.

Option a) Give each ball a name and have some static dictionary mapping their name to the object in the scene (you can make them add themselves on the Awake or Start of the ball). Now you can synchronize the name of the ball that a player holds (a string in oppose to an object). When a client gets the name change, you can handle the name change as looking it up in the static dictionary, and setting it as the ball being held.

Option b)  Synchronize the player AND the balls. Anything logic-related will only happen for the current player. So if the local player holds a ball, the player position will be synced and the ball position will be synced but nothing else will happen for the other players. This of course assumes this works for whatever you are trying to accomplish.

Option c) Serialize the ball. Send the data which describes the ball (size, color, etc) and create a new instance on the client side. This will NOT be tied to any existing balls on the client side. You may need check and destroy whichever ball is already being held. This is probably the least effective way to accomplish this, performance-wise.